# Exiting reading two strings with gets in do while loop

Tags: gets

I am trying to ask a user to type two strings and then the system makes some action as concatenation.
The program I want to be executed at least once and when the first string is equal to '0' to exit.

Could you please help me do it ?

Because something I make wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
    char s1[100],s2[100];
    int len = 0;

    do
    {
        len = strlen(s1);
        printf("\nString1:");
        gets(s1);
        printf("String2:");
        gets(s2);


    } while(s1[0] == '0' && s1[len-1] =='\0');

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As per the condition `(s1[0] == '0' && s1[len-1] == '\0')` the loop will continue only if the first string is '0' and the second string is blank. For all other inputs the loop will exit.

I think your requirement is the condition `(s1[0] != '0')`